# multiclent server connected but not receiving messages properly

Tags: c++, network-programming

I have to create a basic p2p connection with c++ sockets, which means each user has a server for listening onto connections and and a client for connecting, right?

For now I'm trying to create a master client which has a dedicated server and is a client too.

This means creating the server and client in the same program and I have used fork() which creates a child process of the server and the parent is the client. Now, fork works fine and I'm using select() to check sockets for reading data and i have modeled the server on this http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/advanced.html#select

Now when I run the program, the master client is able to connect to its own dedicated server, but the messages don't always get received by the server. Sometimes, it receives it, sometimes it doesn't. Any idea why?

Also, when a second client gets connected to the master client, and it doesn't have it's own server for now, the server shows that it gets a new connection, but when I write the message and send it, it doesn't receive any message from the second client, but it receives a message from the master client sometimes and not always.

**EDIT**: Added cout.flush

**EDIT**: I think forking the process causes some delay when a client and server run on the same program.

**UPDATE:** Added the new server code which causes a delay by one message (in response to the comments)
Here's the code.

SERVER CODE

```
while (1) {
    unsigned int s;
    readsocks = socks;
    if (select(maxsock + 1, &readsocks, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("select");
        return ;
    }
    for (s = 0; s <= maxsock; s++) {
        if (FD_ISSET(s, &readsocks)) {
            //printf("socket %d was ready\n", s);
            if (s == sock) {
                /* New connection */
                cout<<"\n New Connection";
                cout.flush();
                int newsock;
                struct sockaddr_in their_addr;
                socklen_t size = sizeof(their_addr);
                newsock = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&their_addr, &size);
                if (newsock == -1) {
                    perror("accept");
                }
                else {
                    printf("Got a connection from %s on port %d\n",
                            inet_ntoa(their_addr.sin_addr), htons(their_addr.sin_port));
                    FD_SET(newsock, &socks);
                    if (newsock > maxsock) {
                        maxsock = newsock;
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                /* Handle read or disconnection */
                handle(s, &socks);
            }
        }
    }

}


void handle(int newsock, fd_set *set)
{
    char buf[256];
    bzero(buf, 256);
    /* send(), recv(), close() */
    if(read(newsock, buf, 256)<=0){
        cout<<"\n No data";
        FD_CLR(newsock, set);
        cout.flush();
    }

    else {
        string temp(buf);
        cout<<"\n Server: "<<temp;
        cout.flush();
    }
    /* Call FD_CLR(newsock, set) on disconnection */
}
```

Comment: It's probably just the fact that you don't flush after this line: `cout<<"\n server: "<<temp;`, so the output is sitting in the buffer.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I tried cout.flush() it didnt work, also i used printf in place of cout. Still the same problem occurs. My main problem is why the second client is unable to send any messages to the server and why the first client doesn't send the data always. has it got somethng to do with any delay in select?

Comment: Can you show where you placed the flush?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I placed it where you mentioned.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz What I feel, is that select has some kind of delay or something. The while loop seems to pause in midway, and after sending a few messages from the client, server is able to print the last message sent and the previous messages are lost.

Comment: Did you 100% confirm that your code is blocked in `select` during this time? Add an output line before and after to confirm. I think your diagnosis is wrong.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Maybe my diagnosis is wrong. I changed the code a bit, now it's accepting messages from the second client. When I run both client and server in same program by forking the server, then there seems to a lag of one message. The code sort of pauses after getting a new connection, and in the client process, the while loop starts where I enter some text, and send it, only in the next while loop of the client, the server socket newfd becomes ready for reading, and reads the previous text message sent. I hope it's understandable.

Comment: Log when the send happens, when `select` is entered, and when it returns. I still think your analysis may be wrong and you're incorrectly inferring when the message was *received* based on when it was *printed*.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I'm a bit new to this select() and fork(), so I may infer it wrongly. Apologies. Could it be that the socket for listening, is on and it may be blocking the socket for reading from client until the next select function occurs in the next loop?

Comment: 'UDP' and 'connection' are mutually exclusive, as are 'multicast' and 'connection'.

Comment: @EJP I am trying to make a p2p using TCP protocol.